# python call function, when I click on button

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to call the function "function3", when I click on button b1 (in **init**). Thank you.

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        b1 = Button(self.ram2C, text="Aaa", command=???function3???)


    def function1(self, event=None):
        command1

        def function2(event):
            command2

            def function3 (event=None):
               command3
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be defining functions within functions. Generally, it is only a good idea to define a function within another if the inner function is only used by the outer. Find another way of solving your problem, without having nested functions needing to be called from the outside.

Comment: `function3` is nested inside `function1` and `function2`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
b1 = Button(self.ram2C, text="Aaa", command=function1)
def function1(self, event=None):
        command1
        def function2(event):
            command2
            def function3 (event=None):
               command3
            return function3(event)
        return function2(event)
```

In short, `function1` is calling `function2`, and `function2` just calls `function3`. The value returned of `function1` would be the value returned by `function3`.